# extracting a video from streaming server with AVfoundation in ios?

Tags: objective-c, ios, avfoundation

I was able to display a video using NSURL from a webpage into a UIView, but i need to be able to find a way to stream a video from a web server into my iphone using avfoundation. i am a little confused as to what i have to do in order to do this. any pointers would be helpful. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need simple movie playing then take a look at [MPMoviePlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). For more advanced needs start at [AVPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009530)

Comment: thank you, how would i play the video automatically? sorry i am a noob at this.

Comment: The [Multimedia Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingVideo/UsingVideo.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH3-SW1) has some sample code. Also try a search for something like MPMoviePlayerController example.